# Firewall rules using iptables using conditional statement

Tags: iptables

I have firewall rule that should accept all the connections, but drop connections from a ssh brute force attack (except 10.0.0.0/8 range). This rule will block an IP if it attempts more than 24 connections per 10minute.

```
    # Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s ! 10.0.0.0/8 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s ! 10.0.0.0/8 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 600 --hitcount 25 --rttl --name SSH -j DROP
-A INPUT -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

It errors out when I try to start iptables as bad arguement.

```
iptables: Applying firewall rules: Bad argument `10.0.0.0/8'
```

Comment: Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [sf].

Comment: Thx Jim. Going forward I will post on server fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was talked before in SF. `iptables` changed the way it accept parameters. Now the bang should be *before* the parameter, so your lines becomes this:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 ! -s 10.0.0.0/8 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 ! -s 10.0.0.0/8 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 600 --hitcount 25 --rttl --name SSH -j DROP
```

And yes, every blog in internet is wrong.